# Upsert without using on duplicate key MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a mysql statement that upserts into a table without having to use the primary key.

I know of the on duplicate key command but I can't use it here since I'm checking for the uniqueness of two columns that aren't primary keys. I know it would be better to just make these two primary keys, but I can't since this was the schema that was given.

The schema looks like this:

> tbl_order_detail

- key_order_detail
- key_order
- key_product
- some_other_keys

If the key_order,key_product pair is unique then I do a regular insert.
If they aren't unique then I update the row.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works not only with primary keys, but with any unique constraints.

So just create a composite unique index for `(key_order, key_product)` columns and use it.

Comment: Nice catch. Reading is tech. I completely missed that you could do that. Thanks!